# print range of integers in descending or ascending order in java

Tags: java, range, integer

I have an upper bound and a lower bound and I want to return all number number between  the bounds including the bounds. I know python has a range function but I'm sure if java has this method.

Comment: are the numbers in a array... can u detail it further

Comment: No, he has an upper bound and a lower bound.  He said this already.

Comment: so i asked a user for an upper and lower bound input. using those variables i am trying to print all the numbers within that bound. Does using a while or for loop help?

Comment: while (lower < upper) { 
System.out.print(lower); 
lower++;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a for loop.  Do you want to print them or return them?  Your title and question disagree on this.  If you want to return them, you will need to pick the type that you use to contain them.

```
List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
    ret.add(i);
}
return ret;
```

I will leave it as an exercise to print them, or to get them in descending order.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, i wanted to print them. But I know how to do that:
    System.out.print(i + " ");

Thanks for the help mate! :D

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array if integers you can use **IntRange** in Apache Commons Lang:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html

```
IntRange ir = new IntRange(int lower, int upper);
ir.toString();
```

More info of the various Range's you can use here:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/class-use/Range.html

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I totally over-read the question.  I saw a suggestion of an IntRange utility and I just assumed this was the classic "I want an Iterable" request, which I hear often. So ignore the below.

Simplified (without error checking):

```
public static List<Integer> range(final int start, final int end) {
  return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
    public int size() {
      return end - start + 1;
    }
    public Integer get(int i) {
      return start + i;
    }
  };
}
```