# How to turn an int to series of numbers?

Tags: java, integer, println

I am trying to write a Java program that turns a number into series of numbers.

So for example

```
int number = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter your number: ");
number = input.nextInt();
```

Now for example the user typed the number 4, then I want to the program to print it like this:

1 2 3 4

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print range of integers in descending or ascending order in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242497/print-range-of-integers-in-descending-or-ascending-order-in-java)

Comment: Is it a question worth asking?? I mean that this question is such a beginner one. You can easily find it anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were looking for

```
public void printSeriesOfNumbers(int n) {
   for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
       System.out.print(i + " ");
   }
}
```

Comment: I would got to i<=n